# Как проверить количество вхождений одной строки в другой

Tags: c#, строки

Пример: есть первая строка с текстом `"AByrjujABw qr"`, и есть вторая с текстом `"AB"`. Соотвественно, вторая встретилась в первой 2 раза. Как такое посчитать на C#? Есть ли функция готовая, или свою выдумывать?

Comment: По моему лучше всего будет через регулярки

Comment: [Поиск подстроки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Поиск_подстроки).

Comment: Linq-вариант (куда уж без него?): `string a = "AByrjujABw qr"; string b = "AB"; int c = a.Select((_, i) => a.Skip(i).Take(b.Length)).Count(s => s.SequenceEqual(b)); Console.WriteLine(c);`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Дайте и мне:

```
string a = "AByrjujABw qr";
string b = "AB";
int n = (a.Length - a.Replace(b, "").Length) / b.Length;
```

Comment: Я бы даже не подумал про такой простой вариант, однозначно плюсую :)

Comment: Красивое решение. Однако, `Replace` создаёт новую строку. В итоге по расходу памяти может быть неэффективно.

Answer (score 7):

Задачу можно решить с помощью алгоритма [Кнута-Морриса-Пратта](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0)

Пусть у нас есть искомая подстрока `substring`, исходная строка `str`, и символ-разделитель, такой что он не входит ни в `substring`, ни в `str`. Тогда мы можем составить строку вида:
`substring + разделитель + str` и пройтись по ней [префикс-функцией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F):

Привожу код на `Java`, думаю что вам не составит труда переписать его на `C#`

```
public static void main(String args []) {
    String str = "AByrjujABw qr";
    String substring = "AB";
    String full = substring + "#" + str;
    int[] prefix = prefix(full.toCharArray());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(prefix));
}

private static int[] prefix(char[] s){
    int n = s.length;
    int[] pi = new int[n];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        int j = pi[i-1];
        while (j > 0 && s[i] != s[j])
            j = pi[j-1];
        if (s[i] == s[j])  ++j;
        pi[i] = j;
    }
    return pi;
}
```

После прохода префикс-функцией вам нужно пройтись по массиву `prefix` и посчитать количество чисел, равных длине вашей искомой подстроки, это и будет ответом.

Результат выполнения префикс-функции:

> [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]

длина искомой подстроки - 2, число 2 в префиксном массиве встречается 2 раза.

Обратите внимание, что алгоритм даст результат при пересечении подстрок, например имея строки:

```
str = "ABAxxABABAyy";
substring = "ABA";
```

результат будет равен 3, так как `ABA` встречается фактически 3 раза, 2 из которых пересекаются (подстрока `ABABA`)

Comment: КМП - это здорово. Но вот это: `substring + "#" + str` - не здорово. Я уже столько обжигался на выжирании памяти при работе со строками в дотнете...

Answer (score 7):

Вариант с `IndexOf`:

```
string a = "AByrjujABw qr";
string b = "AB";
int c = 0, i = -1;
while ((i = a.IndexOf(b, i + 1)) > -1) ++c;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Если вы хотите исключать пересечения вхождений (`ABA` в `ABABA` находить один раз, а не два), то можно переписать так:

```
int c = 0, i = -b.Length;
while ((i = a.IndexOf(b, i + b.Length)) > -1) ++c;
```

Comment: Хороший вариант: один проход, оптимальный поиск, нет распределения памяти. Единственное, может возникнуть неоднозначность с наложением фрагментов, упомянутая @iksuy. `i + b.Length`?

Comment: @Igor, спасибо, добавил!

Answer (score 6):

Подготовка:

```
var str = "AByrjujABw qr";
var separator = "AB";
```

**Вариант 1 (используем `Split()`):**

```
var splitResult = str.Split(new [] {separator}, StringSplitOptions.None).Length-1;
```

**Вариант 2 (используем `Regex`):**

```
var regexResult = Regex.Matches(str, separator).Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = "AByrjujABw qr";
string b = "AB";
int c = 0, i = -1;
while ((i = a.IndexOf(b, i + 1)) > -1) ++c;
```

Comment: В чем отличие от [моего варианта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/897096/218063)?