# C# IndexOf метод

Tags: c#, indexof

Как сделать, что бы метод IndexOf проверял строку до конца, а не до первого совпадения?

Comment: LastIndexOf https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: LastIndexOf выдаст только последнее вхождение. Что необходимо, не совсем понятно. Может индексы всех вхождений? (поэтому автор пишет "до конца" ?)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/896911/218063

Answer (score 2):

Среди [перегруженных методов IndexOf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2)  есть метод с **указанием стартовой позиции**.

Таким образом, после нахождения первого вхождения можно выполнить следующий поиск с позиции правее найденной, и так до конца, если вхождений несколько.