# Посчитать количество вхождений подстроки в строку

Tags: java, строки, substring

У меня есть две переменные: `text` и `text2`. Переменной `text` присваивается та строка, которую вводит пользователь, а `text2` присваивается значение строки в самом коде. Нужно посчитать, сколько раз строка `text2` входит в строку `text`.

Вот так выглядят переменные:

```
String t = reader.readLine();
String t2 = "get out of my swamp";
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896911

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У самого `String` нет метода `count`, поэтому [используйте самописный](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44838176/5909792):

```
public static int count(String str, String target) {
    return (str.length() - str.replace(target, "").length()) / target.length();
}
```

Использование:

```
// Сколько раз строка t2 встречается в строке t
System.out.println(count(t, t2));

...

String t = "/get out of my swamp/get out of my swamp/";
String t2 = "get out of my swamp";
System.out.println(count(t, t2))
// 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов тоже может сработать, здесь используются регулярные выражения:

```java
public class Substring {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abcabcabc";
        String substr = "abc";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(substr);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        int counter = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            counter++;
        }
        str = str.replaceAll("abc", "defg");
        System.out.println(counter);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Либо такой вариант, может, он будет проще, с использованием split:

```java
String symbol = "о";
String text = "Добрый день!";
System.out.println((text + "\0").split(symbol).length - 1);
```